# python web service for a network appliance

Tags: python

As there are so many options to write web service in python, I am a bit confused. I have developed a network appliance, its about Private VLANs.

I want to add to it authenticated web service over HTTPS.

It won't be accessed by regular users. It will be accessed just by other systems looking for some network information. Maybe at a later point I'll build an ajax web client which will use it.

There are endless python options. I am not a web programmer, nor I have the time to be one.

All I need is something each is easy to learn and to implement with the following requirements:

1. Easy to learn. I just need to expose some sqlite tables/views/queries through authenticated web services.
2. HTTPS support
3. basic authentication, where I implement the authentication script.

Any suggestions?

The OS is OpenBSD.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Numerous python web frameworks exist that can do this. Which one is easiest is difficult to answer, as I'm afraid this is highly subjective. I would suggest you look at web2py. It is well-documented, has a nice API and excellent database support, including for sqlite.